# Is there a way to identify user text selection event globally?

Tags: android, android-service, clipboard

When user select a word (tap to highlight) on any application, is there a way to identify that event from my android application. Currently I'm using clipboard listener to identify when user copy something to clipboard. But I want to identify the word before user copy( at the time user select the word)

FYI: I'm using following method to access clipboard change service

```
private void performClipboardCheck() {
    ClipboardManager cb = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    if (cb.hasPrimaryClip()) {
        ClipData cd = cb.getPrimaryClip();
        if (cd.getDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)){
            System.out.println("Copy performed");
            if(cb.getText().toString().contains(" ")){
                //do something
            }else{
                //do something else 
            }


        } 
    }}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I also need a way to check if the user did a text selection globally.

Comment: Not yet. I had to go with clipboard update event.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way to get the selected text form Edit Text:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                int min = 0;
                int max = editText.getText().length();
                if (editText.isFocused()) {
                    final int selStart = editText.getSelectionStart();
                    final int selEnd = editText.getSelectionEnd();
                    min = Math.max(0, Math.min(selStart, selEnd));
                    max = Math.max(0, Math.max(selStart, selEnd));
                }
                // here is your selected text
                final CharSequence selectedText = editText.getText().subSequence(min, max);
                String text = selectedText.toString();
```

then in order to copy the text to clipboard,

```
myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", text );
        myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
```

if you want to replace the selected text from editText,

```
                int min2 = 0;
                int max2 = editText.getText().length();
                if (editText.isFocused()) {
                    final int selStart = editText.getSelectionStart();
                    final int selEnd = editText.getSelectionEnd();
                    min2 = Math.max(0, Math.min(selStart, selEnd));
                    max2 = Math.max(0, Math.max(selStart, selEnd));
                }
                ClipData abc = myClipboard.getPrimaryClip();
                ClipData.Item item11 = abc.getItemAt(0);
                String text1 = item11.getText().toString();
                editText.getText()
                        .replace(min2, max2, text1, 0, text1.length());
```

Comment: Actually i want to identify the word selection globally. that means my application should be capable of identifying text selection on any other application as well, not only in my application